# How to remove unused overridden toString() methods with Proguard or other tools?

Tags: java, android, proguard, android-proguard

There are some shared codes in both my *Android* project and my *Java* app server project. In the server project I overrode some `toString()` methods for logging, which are not needed in the Android project. Then I optimized the codes in my Android project with *ProGuard*. But when I decompiled the generated *APK*'s *classes.dex*, the `toString()` methods were still there. It can remain as a defect for easy reverse-engineering if I don't remove them. 
I have tried the `-assumenosideeffects` option but it doesn't work. Is there a way to remove these `toString()` methods by editing the *ProGuard* configuration or the *Android* project configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy usage detection, any Object.toString could invoke your class' toString.

Mark every illuminating `toString` with your own compile-time annotation, like

```
@DevelopOnly
@Override
public String toString() { ...
```

And then use an annotation processor (apt) to remove the methods.
There are many nice examples out there.

Collect the classes in an AbstractProcessor and use **ASM** or another library to remove the methods.

Comment: Can you please share this "DevelopOnly" ? Also, is there a similar solution for Kotlin, when you use "data class" (it generates the toString for you, to include all kinds of stuff about the class, including its name, fields names, and values) ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper sorry, java annotation & annotation processing is a tutorial level topic, and on Kotlin I am still unknowing. AFAIK  the syntax is almost the same.

Comment: But the answer you showed here was about this. How could anyone use your solution? :(

Answer (score 0):

No. Proguard won't remove code with references to it.

Your best option would be something to "force" the compiler to drop the lines:
use BuildConfig.DEBUG or a custom constant and wrap the calls in it.

If the compiler finds a constant expression which evaluates to false, it might drop the nested code.

Comment: The code is shared between web and Android, there's no `BuildConfig.DEBUG` available when building the code. Also you can't put an `if` around a method, only the contents. That being said, a `super.toString()` call is less of a problem for reverse engineering.

Comment: Yep, thats why I said "or a custom" constant and yes: you can't wrap a method in an if, hence i said "the calls" like in `if(INDEBUG) log(myObj.toString())`